# Gurevich Classifiability Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, computational-complexity, decidability

I have a question regarding the classification of fragments of first-order logic as presented in The Classical Decision Problem. Page 9 reads:

> The classification problem for the prefix-vocabulary fragments admits a
> complete solution in a form of a finite table. In particular, there are only
> finitely many minimal undecidable fragments with closed prefix sets, and all
> these minimal fragments are standard. This follows from the Classifiability
> Theorem of Gurevich proved in Sect. 2.3. Accordingly, in the main body of
> the book, the prefix-vocabulary classes of interest will be almost exclusively
> standard classes. The Classifiability Theorem has provided guidance for re­search and it provides guidance for this book.

The statement suggests that if we focus on minimal classes which have closed prefix-set then we have a finite number of them and they are in standard form.

**Question 1:** what happens if I lift the closedness condition?

Plus, the statement of the theorem 2.3.40 is technical and I see no mention to maximal fragments.

> Let $D$ be a downward closed collection of prefix-vocabulary classes closed under finite unions. Further, let $U$ be the complement of $D$, and $M$ the collection of minimal closed classes in $U$. Then $M$ is finite, every member of $M$ is standard, and $U$ is the upward
> closure of $M$. In addition, the number of maximal standard members of $D$ is finite.

**Question 2:** how does the theorem apply to maximal decidable fragments?

Comment: I'm confused about Question 2: In my copy of the book, the last sentence of the statement of Theorem 2.3.40 is "In addition, the number of maximal standard members of $\mathcal{D}$ is finite." Doesn't this answer your question about maximal (standard) decidable fragments?

Comment: And on Question 3: Isn't the Bernays-Schönfinkel(-Ramsey) class exactly class A(1) in Table 1.2 of decidable classes on p. 11?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Question 3 removed. Question 2, I guess I will be able to answer once I read fully section 2.3.5. Question 1 remains though.

Comment: Question 1: Right after the definition of "closed" on p. 9, the authors write "Clearly, one can restrict attention to closed prefix sets." The reason is that from the point of view of satisfiability, every prefix set is equivalent to its closure. Indeed, for any prefix set $\Pi$, let $\overline{\Pi}$ be the set of all sub-prefixes of those in $\Pi$. Then any $\Pi$-sentence is an $\overline{\Pi}$-sentence. And conversely, any $\overline{\Pi}$-sentence can be transformed into an equivalent (on non-empty structures) $\Pi$-sentence by adding in "dummy quantifiers".

Comment: Regarding Question 2, I'm honestly confused about what you're looking for. You wrote "I see no mention to maximal fragments", but the theorem explicitly mentions maximal fragments. If you can clarify the question, I'm happy to try to answer it further. If these comments have answered all your question, I can turn them into a real answer.

Comment: @AlexKruckman The question is motivated because the theorem is not in the language of the quoted comment. So it's not direct to have a take away message from its statement. Thanks to your comment I see that I should prove from the theorem that: "The set of minimal undecidable fragments of FOL corresponds to finitely many prefix sets which are in standard form". If I can be sure I can claim "The set of maximal decidable fragments of FOL corresponds to finitely many prefix sets which are in standard form". then the question is answered.

Comment: @AlexKruckman The theorem gives the remark when $D$ is the set of prefixes which lead to decidable instances. "In that case, the number of maximal standard members of $D$  is finite". So one would need to show that standard prefixes describe non-standard versions. This is lemma 2.3.36 I believe.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I found out that exercise 6.0.3 seems to finish the complete answer.  Please feel free to post an answer otherwise I will delete.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer to your own question and accept it? Then it can help future people who might have the same question.